# Android Saving radio button value on another button click using sharedpreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Ive managed to save the text fields but have no clue how to save the chosen value of the radio button when Save is clicked.

The below works fine for a field, but i want to save value for the Sex. The id of the radiogroup is radioSex.

Please can someone help me with the code as ive looked at documentation and always get confused or errors.

Thanks!

Heres my code:

```
public class Settings extends Activity {
    EditText editText;
    Button button;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new Button_Clicker());
        loadSavedPreferences();

    }
    private void loadSavedPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        String name = sharedPreferences.getString("savedname", "Your Name");
        editText.setText(name);
    }

    private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    class Button_Clicker implements Button.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            savePreferences("savedname", editText.getText().toString());

            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To save use it like this**

```
private void saveGenderInPreference() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
    int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    if(selectedId == R.id.male_radio_button)
        editor.putBoolean("is_male", true);
    else
        editor.putBoolean("is_male", false);

    editor.commit();
}
```

Call `saveGenderInPreference()` method in `onClick()` or when you want to save this.

**To load use it like this**

```
RadioButton male = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.male_radio_button);
RadioButton female = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.female_radio_button);
if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("is_male", false))
    male.setChecked(true);
else
    female.setChecked(true);
```

Use this code in `loadSavedPreferences`

**P.S.** Id `R.id.male_radio_button` is indicative. Use your own id here

Comment: Where would i add this, do i add it in the load method?

Comment: It is for saving. To load get the value from preference and use it where you want.

Comment: What if i want to load this? Do i call it in load?

Comment: Yes but for that you will have to use this `sharedPreferences.getBoolean("is_male", false);`

Comment: Okay let me give this a go

Comment: Not sure its working, ive put the sharedPreferences.getBoolean("is_male", false); in my loadsavedpreferences, and have called savegender in my button clicker class but not sure if its right or wrong

Comment: Yes giving it a go now

Comment: Absolutely perfect Rohit, thank you. Am just wondering can i call these sharedpreferences on other java classes within the application to show on other activities?

Comment: Yes you can, no problem at all!

Comment: Great, you were a great help this caused me stress for a whole day, youre the best!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();


radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

         switch(checkedId){
            case R.id.radio0:

               editor.putString("sex", "Male");
            break;

            case R.id.radio1:
               editor.putString("sex", "Female");
            break;

         }
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't really need to save this when it's selected; there is a save button for the same purpose. No need of extra work.